# Uploading files on Dropbox using C# in ASP.NET

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

```
 RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Put(
                    "https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/",
                     new HttpParameterCollection {
                        {"access_token",MYAccessToken},
                        {"path",Path.Combine(this.CurrentPath, Path.GetFileName(@"C:\test\jj.kk\Downloads\1990480.jpg")).Replace("\\","/")},
                        {"overwrite","true"},
                        {"autorename","true"}
                   }
                 );
```

I am using above code for uploading file on Dropbox but giving following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> RequestResult : { "error": "Content-Type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) may not be one of (\'application/x-www-form-urlencoded\', \'multipart/form-data\')" }
>
> Httpheader : 
>   {Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Dropbox-Request-Id: 4029d2ae041cf1f25d8f58d06d158b83
>   X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noimageindex
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 15:24:17 GMT
>   Server: nginx
>   }

Is there any other way of uploading files on Dropbox in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're getting is indicating that the issue with your API request is that the `Content-Type` has an unexpected value. That is, you (via the library you're using, presumably) are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That isn't an allowed format for the [Dropbox API /1/files_put endpoint](https://meta-dbdev.dev.corp.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put), which expects the raw file data in the body of the request.

To answer your actual question though, there is another way to upload to Dropbox in ASP.NET. You can use Dropbox API v2, instead of Dropbox API v1 as you have here. (And in fact you should, since [Dropbox API v1 is deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/).)

To do so, we highly recommend using the official SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet

Alternatively, you can use the HTTP endpoints directly, e.g.,:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload

Comment: {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}]

Comment: {Error in call to API function "files/get_metadata": request body: could not decode input as JSON}

Comment: RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Post("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata", new HttpParameterCollection
                     {
                         {"path",this.CurrentPath}
                        
                     }, authorization: "Bearer JeLfJM8bGRAAAAAAAAAAHe3oxMxsHdk7cs3xl1TCY_ljB5eh56YIS3d6Ni7iIPo0",
                        headers: null,
                      contentType: "application/json");

Comment: For reference, this was posted as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998627/error-while-fetching-files-and-folder-from-dropbox-using-api-v2-in-c-sharp

Comment: yeah that question was posted by me, still not able to find solution :(